# Android Touch Event determining duration

Tags: android, touch

How does one detect the duration of an Android 2.1 touch event?  I would like to respond only if the region has been pressed for say 5 seconds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try mixing [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)/[`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to achieve this.

Sample code:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         checkGlobalVariable();
    }
};

// Other init stuff etc...

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Execute your Runnable after 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds.
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        mBooleanIsPressed = true;
    }

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if(mBooleanIsPressed) {
            mBooleanIsPressed = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you only need to check if `mBooleanIsPressed` is `true` in the `checkGlobalVariable()` function.

One idea I came up with when I was writing this was to use simple timestamps (e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis()`) to determine the duration between `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Comment: Ok.  This is something I need on most of my Activity Screens.  How would I enable listening on the Activity screen.  I have implemented the onTouchEvent listener in the activity, but how do you enable this for the activity, so that the onTouchEvent gets called when user touches activity screen. Thanks

Comment: Most examples are in terms of Canvas etc.  My onTouchEvent is not getting called when the user touches Activity screen

Comment: @Androider: Maybe you're looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)?

Comment: i'm looking for something like getContentView()?

Comment: I see how to set to layout .. but there should be a get view

Comment: I suppose I could use fineViewById(layoutId) like for components and set the activity as its onTouchEvent listener.  Seems like this might not be best place however

Comment: I want to get the current content view and set its onTouchListener

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279182/android-how-to-register-ontouchevent-for-entire-activity-main-content-view/5279252#5279252   I have answered that here

Comment: Timestamps might work well, I think that is simpler.  Not sure how accurate it is however.

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks a lot! One thing to note for my use case was since my view was housed in a pager (i.e. could be scrolled away), I needed to also cancel the handler in the MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL switch case.  This way my handler wouldn't go off when the touch event was stolen by the pager

Answer (score 24):

```
long eventDuration = event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't use unix timestamps in this case. Android offers it's own time measurement.

```
long eventDuration = 
            android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() 
            - event.getDownTime();
```